# GoogleMap not showing the changes I made

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a fragment in which I use (or rather, want to use) Google Maps.

The fragment is between an actionbar and a tabhost, the fragment's layout is

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/search_map_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seekbar_min"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seekbar_mid"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/seekbar_max"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

and it looks like this

[image]

Now I want to actually work with it. I followed Google's Map documentation/tutorial and ended up with this code

```
public class SearchFriendsMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static View view;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        buildGoogleApiClient(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        /* If you place a mapfragment inside a fragment, it crashes when the fragment is
         * loaded a 2nd time. Below solution was found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/
         * 14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi
         */
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.removeView(view);
            }
        }
        try {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment.
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_friends_map, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            // Map is already there, just return view as it is.
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        googleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context context) {
        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, "BUILDING GOOGLE API CLIENT");
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, "MAP READY");

        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, String.valueOf(googleMap.getMapType()));
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, String.valueOf(googleMap.getMapType()));

        //map = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, "CONNECTED");

        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

        if (lastLocation != null) {
            Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude()));
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
            //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 5));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LogUtil.TAG, "CONNECTION FAILED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LogUtil.TAG, "CONNECTION SUSPENDED");
    }
}
```

Today I updated to the new Android 24.0.2 SDK and Google Play Services v22. I adjusted the gradle file accordingly and it all builds fine.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
```

There are no errors or warnings in the code and the fragment loads everything without complaining.
Required permissions and API key are also set in the manifest.

However, I seem unable to actually interact with the map. The overriden methods all run (I see the log for each method in logcat)

[image]

but especially these 2 lines seem to not do anything.

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

The map just shows as in the picture above. The current location isn't shown (GPS, wifi is enabled), nor is the map type changed. Especially the map type not changing I find weird, because in my logs I can see it actually did change (from 1 to 4).

Where am I going wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from @AbhinavPuri I got it to work. What I had to do was

Change

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

to

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Made my fragment `extend Fragment` instead of `extend SupportMapFragment` and, because I use a GoogleMap in a fragment and not in an activity, I had to move the 'map getting' code to the onCreateView. If you don't, findFragmentById returns null, because in the onCreate, the view is not yet inflated.

Now using this piece of code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    /* If you place a mapfragment inside a fragment, it crashes when the fragment is
     * loaded a 2nd time. Below solution was found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/
     * 14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi
     */
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.removeView(view);
        }
    }
    try {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment.
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_friends_map, container, false);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        // Map is already there, just return view as it is.
    }

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}
```

Using getChildFragmentManager because the SupportMapFragment is nested in another fragment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not linked map received by onMapReady with map you have in your xml fragment, so your fragment just gets loaded, therefore, you see a map, but your changes not reflected.

Code from my app working fine for me :

```
// In my onCreate(..) :
....
((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
....
```

Then :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;   // map is your global variable.

    // Everything below works fine : 
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    map.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm 99% sure I already tried that, you can see I commented that out (the `map = googleMap`). But I will give it a shot tomorrow

Comment: Why do you call `.getMapAsync()` on `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))`? Why not just call `getMapAsync();`?

Comment: This is how is done in map dev tutorials : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_map_code

Comment: The reason for using .getMapAsync(), is to set the callback on the layout's map fragment and not on any fragment.

Comment: I keep getting NPEs on findFragmentById, also I'm using SupportMapFragment

Comment: ^That was because I was calling it before the view was created, not sure how you got that to work in the onCreate

Comment: I can call findFragmentById because I am not extending SupportMapFragment, I don't need to do that, I just have ActionBarActivity extending class in my app.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway I got it to work with a little bit of tweaking, you put me in the right direction.

Comment: Then, plz tell me also the tweaking you have done, so that I also get updated, and also plz mark the answer as correct to close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't moved the camera to your position. By animating or moving the camera to your Latitude and Longitude you can get what you are trying to get:

```
private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(-33.88,151.21);
private static final LatLng MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLng(37.4, -122.1);

private GoogleMap map;
... // Obtain the map from a MapFragment or MapView.

// Move the camera instantly to Sydney with a zoom of 15.
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(SYDNEY, 15));

// Zoom in, animating the camera.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());

// Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

// Construct a CameraPosition focusing on Mountain View and animate the camera to that position.
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(MOUNTAIN_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: If you read the other answers you will see that the issue was with setup of the map