# Google Maps API v2 with API 21

Tags: android, api, google-maps, marker

I'm updating my app to support API 21 - Android 5.0.But Google maps do not work. I changed the getMap() to getMapAsync() and Google map is loaded but it doesn't display the pin. I can see only oceans:) but not coordinates specified on my code. Why can't I see the pin on the map?
My code is below:

```
LatLng position = new LatLng(otelObject.getLatitude(),
                otelObject.getLongitude());
        orangeMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(position).icon(orangeMarker);
        mMap.addMarker(marker);
```

---

```
 CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLng(new LatLng(obj
                                        .getLatitude(), obj
                                        .getLongitude()));
                        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

I'm debugging and i recognized that  it doesn't setup the map.

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
    // map.

    new SupportMapFragment() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    mMap = googleMap;
                    setUpMap();
                }
            });
```

I called it onActivityCreated and on resume but I'm debugging and it is not going to setUpMap() but why?

Comment: "I can see only oceans:) but not coordinates specified on my code" -- where is your code that changes the map camera to the coordinates you are interested in?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549521/googlemap-not-showing-the-changes-i-made/27590571#27590571, might be related

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

to your fragment.xml

And try using `extend Fragment` instead of `extend SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I do use android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" and my fragment extends from Fragment but it doesn't work. I edited my question

Comment: Can you post some logcat, error messages warnings you received? That would help to track the issue faster..

Comment: Check to see if the Google Play Services is installed on the testing device... because the documentation states that "In the case where Google Play services is not installed on the user's device, the callback  will not be triggered until the user installs it."  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)