# how to show google map in own android app using getMapAsync

Tags: android

i want to show google map in my own android app...i used google map api key in manifest.im using getMapAsync().but its not working..
code is below is there any mistake i had done.please help me..
thank you...

here is xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          tools:context=".ClinicMap"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:apiKey="AIzaSyCbtSjGcG1g2u9H-hfuO6Tx7F442ZndDb4"/>
```

here is my main activity

```
public class ClinicMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clinic_map);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

 //        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 //        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Mumbai, India, and move the camera.
    LatLng mumbai = new LatLng(19.0128, 72.8246);
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mumbai));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mumbai, 4));
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("mumbai")
            .snippet("The most populous city in India.")
            .position(mumbai));
    }
 }
```

when i used MapFragment i got error " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference"

when i used SupportMapFragment
[output will be like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOFV9.jpg)

Comment: Follow example from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549521/googlemap-not-showing-the-changes-i-made

Comment: have you get any error?? post catlog

Comment: no.@  Ravi Vaghela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your API key in Manifest.xml not in the layout file, if the key is not in the manifest file you won't have access to the map service and your fragment will show nothing.

Go to your manifest and check if you have added the following lines.

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

and INSIDE `<application>` tag:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Also you need to check of your mapFragment object is correctly created, usually I use this block of code to be sure that I'm not passing a null reference to getMapAsync().

```
fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        if(fragment == null){
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            fragment =SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_fragment, fragment).commit();

        }
        if (fragment != null){
            fragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }
```

I've used this in a simple Fragment, you have a FragmentActivity so you maybe need to do some little correction to fit it to your situation.

EDIT:

I've noticed that you're class extends a FragmentActivity, the code I've wrote works with a class which extends Fragment. 
In my mind I have two possible solution:

1. Create a `FragmentActivity` and another class which `extends Fragment` and `implements OnMapReadyCallback` where you create and manipulate your map.
2. Create a simple activity, in its layout.xml create a fragment and instantiate the map.
   In this case you should have something like this:

MAP_LAYOUT.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

ACTIVITY.java:

I'll write only particulars of `OnCreate()`, `SetUpMapIfYouNeed()` and `SetUpMap()`, not the whole class.

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(getIntent().getExtras());
        this.title = bundle.getString("name");
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        //Other lines of code
        //...
        //...
        }


/**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

/**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //Move the map to a specific point


    }
```

Comment: Do you still have an empty map or you got the null object reference error?

Comment: I've added some details in my answer, when I've used them my map has worked correctly, let me know if you will fix the problem ;)

Comment: Thank you @Zanna..actully there is probliem with API key and fragment..now its working..thank you so much..

Comment: Glad to be useful.
If the answer has worked remember to accept it, so other people with a similar problem could find an answer easily